# What's the efficient way to write a timestamp-value pair timeline in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm working on some code where a value can change over time and I need to keep track of that value over time so I can get the most recent value for any timestamp. I'm using Moment.js for timestamp manipulation.

I'm optimizing for a case where typically the value pair will never change over hundreds of thousands of timestamps, or rarely change, but I still need to know if / when it does, and what it was most recently at any point in time. Timestamp queries before the earliest recorded pair should come back false.

```
class Timeline {
    constructor() {
        this.valuePairs = []
    }
    setValueAt(value, timestamp) {
        this.valuePairs.push({ timestamp, value })
    }
    getValueAt(timestamp) {

        // obviously I could iterate through this.valuePairs brute force, get 
        // the difference between each value-pair's timestamp and the target 
        // timestamp, returning the value with the smallest difference, but I 
        // feel bad about even writing this code, it's incredibly 
        // inefficient, and for big datasets, this would create a massive 
        // array to search through and take up memory

        let earliest = Infinity
        let closest = {
            value: false,
            difference: Infinity,
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.valuePairs.length; i++) {
            let valuePair = this.valuePairs[i]
            let difference = timestamp - valuePair.timestamp
            if (valuePair.timestamp < earliest) earliest = valuePair.timestamp
            if (difference < closest.difference) {
                closest.difference = difference
                closest.value = value
            }
        }
        if (closest.value && timestamp > earliest) {
            closest.value
        } else {
            return value
        }
    }
}
```

This is so inefficient that it basically would crash any program processing large batches of data. But I honestly couldn't think of a good way to go about it. What's a more efficient way to write this class?

Comment: How large are we talking about?

Comment: The data set is sorted, right? So just use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) or [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search)

Comment: @Bergi Those are just more efficient brute force searches, no? Smart brute force lol. See my edit at the top, since I'm optimizing for a scenario where the data almost never actually changes, I feel there should be an alternative that makes more sense than interpolation search. I'm thinking I should also not need to keep track of each individual timestamps, but rather track time ranges.

Comment: @Bergi See edit, clarified. Just hundreds of thousands of timestamp entries. But maybe 10K different timelines, each updated a few hundred thousand times.

Comment: Uh, yes, you'd only store the timestamp-value pairs where the value actually changes? Where does your data come from, does it contain lots of duplicate values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [Trie Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to improve efficiency of your program. To use `Trie Tree`, you should covert `timestamp` to `year`, `month`, `date`, `hour`, `minute`, `second` and `millisecond`. And every element represents a node in `Trie Tree` as shown in the below. When you search a `timestamp` to find its value, you can look up a node in the `Trie Tree` which have a same `year` as the `timestamp`, then the same `month` and so on. If there's not a node which has the same `year` as the `timestamp`, you should look up the nearest neighbor. And this algorithm  has constant time complexity. In the worst case, you should compare every millisecond and find the nearest value, and this will cost O(1000) time.
[image]